# counting data rows in array outside model code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, rows

hi i have this code where i want to count whether there is a data returned or none. this is my code

```
<?php foreach($content1 as $c){
        if($c == 1){  ?>
        <a href = '<?php echo base_url().'Employees/updateidinfo/'.$data; ?>' class = 'btn btn-info pull-right fa fa-edit'>&nbsp Update</a>
  <?php }else{ ?>
        <a href = '<?php echo base_url().'Employees/updateidinfo/'.$data; ?>' class = 'btn btn-info pull-right fa fa-edit'>&nbsp Add</a>

<?php }} ?>
```

i want to do is if `$c` returned 1 row, it will show this button else show other button.

my model is

```
public function spouse(){

    $query = $this->db->get_where('emp_fi_s', array('ID_NUM' => $this->uri->segment(3)));
    return $query->result();
}
```

can i do this without creating another model function that have `return $query->num_rows();`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach($content1 as $c){
        if($c == 1){  ?>
        <a href = '<?php echo base_url().'Employees/updateidinfo/'.$data; ?>' class = 'btn btn-info pull-right fa fa-edit'>&nbsp Update</a>
  <?php }else{ ?>
        <a href = '<?php echo base_url().'Employees/updateidinfo/'.$data; ?>' class = 'btn btn-info pull-right fa fa-edit'>&nbsp Add</a>

<?php }} ?>    

change 

    if($c == 1)

    to

    if($c != ""  && $c == 1){
```